# вернуть значение с stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Хочу, чтобы моя процедура возвращала Id после insert-а, а это id AUTO INCREMENT Field. Как это сделать?

```
@GroupId BIGINT,
@EventId BIGINT, 
@EventMarketId BIGINT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Market(GroupId, EventId, EventmarketId)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
        VALUES  (@GroupId, @EventId, @EventMarketId)
END
```

Comment: Покажите определение таблицы market.

Answer (score 1):

Триггер не лучшая реализация этой задачи, вам подойдет один из вариантов ниже:

1. [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

   SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
2. [IDENT_CURRENT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

   SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)

   Добавьте одну из этих строк во внутрь вашего `BEGIN ... END`

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MyProcedure
  @GroupId BIGINT,
  @EventId BIGINT, 
  @EventMarketId BIGINT ,
  @id INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO Market (GroupId, EventId, EventmarketId)
     VALUES (@GroupId, @EventId, @EventMarketId)
     set @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
  declare @myID int
  EXEC MyProcedure 10,10,10, @id = @myID OUTPUT
  select @myID
```